# Is openssl wrongly rejecting this session request?

Tags: openssl, debian, freeswitch

I have OpenSSL 1.1.1n on a Debian11 server, configured to use `MinProtocol = TLSv1.2`

When the server receives a `ClientHello` as below:

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 142
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 138
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

with `Record Layer Version` set to **TLSv.1** but with `Handshake Version` set to **TLSv1.2** it rejects it with a `Protocol Version` alert and closes the connection, when according to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#appendix-E this looks like an accepted behavior and should not be rejected.

Is openssl breaching the RFC here, or am I missing a configuration parameter that I can adjust to fix this?

On the other hand, when I decrease the `MinProtocol` to **TLSv1**, the server accepts the ClientHello and responds with a **TLSv1** Handshake, which causes the entire session to be over **TLSv1** and is not accepted by the other party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that setting both `MinProtocol` and `MaxProtocol` as below:

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1
MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

fixes the both issues.